# Можно только + инфинитив () и только + дополнение

Tags: пунктуация

***Болезнью недоверия можно только заразиться() и только от того, кто вас однажды предал.***

Нужна ли запятая перед ***и только***? Является ли выражение "и только от того" предложением? Я  думаю, что запятая всё-таки нужна...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***Болезнью недоверия можно только заразиться() и только от того, кто вас однажды предал.***
>
> Нужна ли запятая перед ***и только?***

Можно поставить запятую, можно  — тире.

[См.:](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123#pp123)

> **§ 84. Присоединительные члены** предложения имеют характер сведений добавочных, сообщаемых попутно, в дополнение к содержанию основного
>   высказывания. Такие члены предложения выделяются запятыми и обычно
>   вводятся словами и сочетаниями слов (частицами, союзами или их
>   сочетанием) даже, ***в особенности, особенно, главным образом, в том
>   числе, в частности, например, и притом, и потому, да и, да и только,
>   да и вообще, и, тоже, и тоже, причем*** и др.
>
> <...>
>
> Возможно выделение присоединительных членов и при помощи тире,
>   особенно в конечной позиции...

Comment: Соглашусь, спасибо! Я практически сразу отправила ответ автору, но не с запятой, а  с тире.

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно неоднозначная ситуация.С одной стороны, только - это выделительная частица и обособления не требует.Если убрать "только", получится

Болезнью недоверия можно  заразиться  от того, кто вас однажды предал.

Запятая не нужна, но тогда читать нужно без паузы.

С другой стороны, если сделать паузу при чтении, получится присоединительная конструкция, тогда нужна запятая.

Как читаете, такова и пунктуация.

Answer (score 1):

Смысл предложения останется *в точности тем же*, что и в случае замены союза "**и**" на "**причем**":

> Болезнью недоверия можно только заразиться, *причём* только от того, кто
>   вас однажды предал.

В этом случае необходимость в запятой очевидна, а поскольку союз "и" в исходном предложении выполняет ту же функцию присоединения уточняющего оборота, что и "причём", то запятая нужна.

Comment: Да, всё верно, отлично!